# hide system bar on android devices

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to hide android system bar on bottom while my app is running ? My problem is when I run my app in android tablet, the bottom system bar overlaps my app and when I run my app in mobile, it doesn't hide it. The app uses available space only(that exclude the bottom status bar). It's fine to use my app like this but the problem is when I run app in tablet the system bar overlaps my app. I google it and I read somewhere it can be achieved by creating native extension. Is it possible to hide the system bar ? If not, is it possible to run my app without system bar overlapping the app ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
in your AndroidManifest.xml.

You may try it with whole application or some Activity such as,

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/icon"
   android:icon="@string/app_name"
   android:icon="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/activity_name"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

Comment: This attribute is related to app itself.